# IEnumerable Select statement with ternary operator

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, ternary-operator

I have an odd behavior using an `IEnumerable<string>` with a ternary operator and a `Select` statement.
I have two lists with different objects. One list contains `Enums` the other list contains objects. Those objects do have a `String` property.
If one list is `null` or `empty` I want to get the values of the other list.
Here is some code:

```
public class ExportItem
{
    public string Type;
    ...
}

public enum ExportType
{
    ExportType1,
    ExportType2,
    ...
}
```

The `List<ExportItem>` is always filled by a config file. The `List<ExportType>` is filled if command line arguments are provided. So if `List<ExportType>` is filled I want to use them, otherwise I want to use those from the config file.
So my code ist like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> exportTypes = MyListOfExportTypes != null &&
    MyListOfExportTypes.Any() ? MyListOfExportTypes.Select(x => x.ToString()) :
    MyListOfExportItems.Select(x => x.Type);
```

The thing is that `exportTypes` is `null` but I don't get it...
When I do this with `if-else` everything works as expected. Also if `exportTypes` is of type `List<string>` and I call `ToList()` after the `Select` statement everything works fine.
Using `var a = MyListOfExportTypes.Select(x => x.ToString());` and `var b = MyListOfExportItems.Select(x => x.Type);` does work as expected.
Must be something with the ternary operator and/or `IEnumerable`. But what?

Or what do I miss? Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I now have a screenshot...
[image]

Note that the code above `foreach` works nevertheless...

Comment: how do you know exportTypes is null ?

Comment: By debugging the code.

Comment: if you call `exportTypes.ToList` do you get a NullReferenceException?

Comment: It works absolutely fine for me.  Are you sure both `MyListOfExportTypes` and `MyListOfExportItems` are not null?  Actually, that would probably give a different issue.

Comment: @Selman22 So this is really odd. No I don't! Right after executing the `Select` statement and hovering over `exportTypes` the debugger says `null` but I can call `ToList()` and everything is as expected. Some kind of VS 2010 bug?

Comment: @SimonLinder Are you saying that the debugger is on the next line and still showing `exportTypes` as `null`?  It should be `null` until the debugger gets past that line.  Maybe a screenshot is in order?

Comment: @SimonLinder Are you sure where you're debugging it `exportTypes` has been assigned (i.e. try stopping on the line beneath this).

Comment: `Select` actually returns a query that is ready to be executed. VS Debugger should allow you to evaluate the expression and see the results when you hover the mouse to your variable. maybe your debugger doesn't support this feature and shows null instead.. I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Selman22 My debugger does. If I debug `var a = MyListOfExportTypes.Select(x => x.ToString());` I get a proper result.

Comment: Maybe some screenshot of the debugging would help. Like this I feel like we're all guessing.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez screenshot added

Comment: @SimonLinder: What LINQ provider are you using? Are you seeing this behavior during a unit test or during normal execution?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker This occurs during normal execution. I'm using nothing special just normal VS 2010...

Comment: I'm not able to recreate it either.  Can you create a new project with only this code that exhibits the behavior?

Comment: @WyattEarp Actually I didn't do that as it works as it is. It seems to be some kind of VS Bug or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this was answered,
But I think that this is related to the fact that you are using LINQ deferred execution.

When writing LINQ queries,
there is a difference between creating the query and executing it.

Writing the select statement, is creating the query, adding ToList() executes it.
Think of it like writing SQL query in SQL server console (that's the writing stage),
and once you hit F5 (Or the play button) you execute it.

I hope this little code sample will help to clarify it.

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public void Test()
        {
            //Here I'm creating a List of Some class
            var someClassItems = new List<SomeClass> { 
                new SomeClass { X = 1, Y = 1 }, 
                new SomeClass { X = 2, Y = 2 } 
            };

            //Here I'm creating a Query
            //BUT, I'm not executing it, so the query variable, is represented by the IEnumerable object
            //and refers to an in memory query
            var query = someClassItems.
                Select(o => o.X);

            //Only once the below code is reached, the query is executed.
            //Put a breakpoint in the query, click the mouse cursor inside the select parenthesis and hit F9
            //You'll see the breakpoint is hit after this line.
            var result = query.
                ToList();

        }
    }
```